# Flutter: how to make it work to show a "Please authenticate" page throughout the app whenever a variable changes without calling it on every page?

Tags: flutter, dart

So my idea is that I made a "Please authenticate" page where nothing else shown than a fingerprint and a text that says "Touch for authentication", then the app bring up the device fingerprint / face id authentication.

I want to show this page everytime when a boolean variable changes without telling it explicitly on every page.

I have a class that has a `needToAuthenticate` boolean variable, if it is true, I want to show the "Touch for authentication" page. So if I set this variable true after 10 minutes, this page shown up and does not let user go anywhere else until it authenticates.

If I have 2 pages in my app, I don't want this:

Page 1:

```
...
_needToAuthenticate = CustomAuthentication.getNeedToAuthenticate();

@override
build() {
   return  _needToAuthenticate ? showAuthenticationPage() : showTheActualThingThisPageNeedToHave();
}
...
```

Page 2:

```
...
_needToAuthenticate = CustomAuthentication.getNeedToAuthenticate();

@override
build() {
   return  _needToAuthenticate ? showAuthenticationPage() : showTheActualThingThisPageNeedToHave();
}

...
```

As you can see, code duplication. Don't like it. I would like if a change listeners is checking the boolean variable in the `CustomAuthentication`, if it is set to true it will show the "Please authenticate" page. The Page 1 and Page 2 should look like:

Page 1:

```
...

@override
build() {
   return showTheActualThingThisPageNeedToHave();
}

...
```

Page 2:

```
...

@override
build() {
   return  showTheActualThingThisPageNeedToHave();
}

...
```

But if the variable set true, in front of these pages the "Please authenticate" page will be shown.

At the moment I use a `while (needToAuthenticate) authenticate();` code but this is looping indefinitely until user authenticates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you create a `AuthenticateWidget` with your code and wrap all your screens with it?

Comment: That's something what I would prefer to avoid. Taking care to put that on every screen and hope that someone does not access to sensitive information because you forget to place it...

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [inheritedWidget](https://medium.com/@mehmetf_71205/inheriting-widgets-b7ac56dbbeb1) together with [streamingSharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/streaming_shared_preferences)-plugin.

Create a widget to hold the 'setting':

```dart
class AppSettings extends InheritedWidget {
  // Preferences
  static String _needToAuthenticateKey = 'MY_KEY';

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;

  static AppSettings of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<AppSettings>();

  AppSettings({Widget child, StreamingSharedPreferences preferences})
      : _needToAuthenticate = preferences.getBool(_needToAuthenticateKey , defaultValue: true),
        super(child: child);

  final Preference<bool> _needToAuthenticate;

  Stream<bool> streamNeedToAuthenticate() => _needToAuthenticate;

  void setNeedToAuthenticate(bool value) => _needToAuthenticate.setValue(value);
}
```

and wrap the entry point of your application:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:streaming_shared_preferences/streaming_shared_preferences.dart';
// TODO Do not forget to import the AppSettings here

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final StreamingSharedPreferences _preferences;

  const MyApp({StreamingSharedPreferences preferences})
      : this._preferences = preferences;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppSettings(
      preferences: this._preferences,
      child: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            AppSettings.of(context).streamNeedToAuthenticate()
                       .listen((event) {(/*Ask for identification*/)})
            return MaterialApp(
              title: applicationName,
              home: /*Your application*/,
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this for your use case but I use the plugin in a similar way.